# Preparedstatement compile time

Tags: java, teradata, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using `jdbctemplate.queryForList(String sql, Object... args)` method to fetch results from teradata. Sometimes I observed that this method takes more time than when i run the same query on teradata studio. Is it because of compilation of sql at web services side?

How a prepared statement will compile the sql statement and the arguments passed to it & how much time it takes for compilation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference ? How much time takes for both. Can you explain more ?

Comment: I could see at least a couple seconds of delay through jdbc template

Comment: A couple of seconds is most likely not related to compiling a query. You'd have to have one massive query for it to take that long. There are plenty of things that can affect the time taken, and you'll have a hard time distinguishing those, as it's pretty much impossible to have both parties run the query in the exact same environment and situation.

Comment: @pkgajulapalli just for the record consider accepting solution in case i was your help in any way

Comment: Are there any parameters passed? A Prepared Statement without parameters is useless and when you submit it in Studio you're probably not using parameters (although I wouldn't expect a huge difference in compilation time).

Comment: @dnoeth, I'm passing certain parameters.

Comment: Compare passing parameters vs. hard coded values in your application, not compared to Studio.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):
`PreparedStatement` is derived from `Statement` .If you want to execute a `Statement` object many times, it usually reduces execution time to use a `PreparedStatement` object instead.

The main feature of a `PreparedStatement` object is that, unlike a `Statement` object, it is given a SQL statement when it is created. The advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is sent to the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the `PreparedStatement` object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the `PreparedStatement` is executed, the DBMS can just run the `PreparedStatement` SQL statement without having to compile it first.

If you want to see `PreparedStatement` interface then select the `PreparedStatement` in eclipse and press F3

**EDIT :**

In reponse to @Kayaman there is no difference between running a `PreparedStatement` and `Statement` there can a lot of factors affecting the compilation time depends upon the environment or the query if it is massive query or small one. You really need to take a close look why it's taking additional couple of seconds.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: @Kayaman time taken for compilation is something that depends on the environment. I don't think there is fixed time for compilation process. If the query is big or small varies

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in **my** comment.